# Inserting new cells into table via drop down list that doesn't replace existing cells

Tags: excel, vba

My goal: Create a table that can start from one column and one cell, which you can remove or edit each cell / row - or add a new main or sub-item via a drop-down.

Seems simple enough, however I've had a host of troubles trying to do this.

Here is an image representation of what I want

[image]

This would be the format for how it looks when I add the new row, I select the associated value and then make it a sub-directorate, but adding a new row and then insert the value into the next column. When clicking an individual cell it would have a drop-down that says 'add, edit, delete'

Currently, my problem is that the items in the first column are being overwritten by the add, edit, and delete options. And that when adding the value from the add option, it does not extend the list and thus not apply the same macro to that item.

See code for the main and the user form connected to the add option.

```vb
'Event code, Target variable contains the cell or range that has been changed
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    'Interesect method returns a range object of a rectangular intersection of two or more cell ranges
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("Table3")) Is Nothing Then
     
        'Select Case statment performs one out of several groups of statements based on a condition
        Select Case Target
     
            'If text in cell is equal to "value" the associated Macro is ran
            Case "Edit": MacEd
            Case "Delete": MacRev
            Case "Add": MacAdd
     
        'Stops Select Case statement
        End Select
    End If
    End Sub
```

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim inputValue As String
    
    ' Get the input value from the TextBox
    inputValue = TextBox1.Value
    
    ' Check if the input value is empty
    If inputValue = "" Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a value in the text box.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    'if user says item is sub directorate add cell to next column
    If Controls("CheckBox1").Value Then
        If ComboBox1.Value = "" Then
            MsgBox "Add Parent Directorate"
        Else
            ' Insert a new row above the active cell
            Range(activeCell, activeCell).Offset(1, 1).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
            
            ' Add the input value to the newly inserted row
            activeCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = inputValue
            
            ' Clear the TextBox
            TextBox1.Value = ""
            
            ' Provide a confirmation message
            MsgBox "Item added successfully!", vbInformation
        End If
    ' else add row below current
    Else
            ' Insert a new row above the active cell
            Range(activeCell, activeCell).Offset(-1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
            
            ' Add the input value to the newly inserted row
            activeCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = inputValue
            
            ' Clear the TextBox
            TextBox1.Value = ""
            
            ' Provide a confirmation message
            MsgBox "Item added successfully!", vbInformation
    End If
    Unload UserForm1
End Sub
```

code fundamentally works but I can't figure out how to get this to execute the way I want.

Comment: Having trouble with inserting and editing, why not share the code of MacEd, MacRev and MacAdd.

Comment: MacAdd opens the userform, edit and remove have no contents inside them other than a msg box, saying "this adds, xyz" @taller_ExcelHome

Answer (score 0):

The code demonstrates inserting a row above/below the active cell and update adjacent columns in new row. ActiveCell ends up in the inserted row when adding above as existing shifts down. Different behavior occurs when inserting below.

btw, `Range(activeCell, activeCell)` equals `ActiveCell`.

```vb
Sub InsertDemo()
    [a1:a5] = Application.Transpose(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
    [a2].Select
    ' Insert a row ABOVE the active cell
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
    ' Activecell is in the new inserted row
    ' Update cell in next column
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1) = "AboveRow-NextCol"
    ' Insert a row BELOW the active cell
    [a4].Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown
    ' Activecell is above the new inserted row
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = "BelowRow-NextCol"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, though this doesnt solve the problem. The core problem is that the dropdown list overwrites the value when selecting its option AND that when adding the cells it doesnt extend the table, would fixin this bit in the code remedy that?

Comment: Your code in OP isn't related with dropdown. I would suggest you provide the detail of user's operation. eg. select B10, input text, click button ... the expected result is ...

Comment: This is fair, there is no real code connected to the drop down other than the original case selection. I did not think to clarify.  also have another question relative to the code you provide here, does this work on any group of cells or is it only relative to the defined range in the array [a1:a5]

Comment: This is just sample code for demonstration. Please update as needed.